# nautilus cannot open display

Tags: nautilus, sudo, gtk, init

I looked at all the other help, and cannot solve this issue.  I am sure it is something small/simple that I am missing - but I just can't see what it is.

I VNC to my Ubuntu server, just updated to 18.04.3 LTS.
I open a place, such as Places > Desktop.
I right-click "Open in Terminal".
Nothing happens.  That used to open a Nautilus window for me.
I go to Applications > Accessories > Byobu Terminal.
It is blank, so I go to File > New Window.  Now it has the terminal windows with my user info.
I enter `sudo nautilus`.  It asks for my password. I enter it.  It then shows

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:2962): Gtk-WARNING ** 12:24:05.100: cannot open display:
```

I did a bunch of googling. I looked at the related posts on here.
I made sure that X11Forwarding wa enabled in \etc\ssc\ssh_config & sshd_config (it already was configured that way).
I tried entering `xhost +SI:localuser:root`. But, that resulted in
`xhost:  unable to open display ""`.
`xhost local:root` and `xhost +` give me the same result.
I reinstalled nautilus.  I installed nautilus-admin.
I have the same result with or without `sudo`.  Then I think "Maybe iut isn't nautilus".
So I tried opening Thunar, `thunar`, which resulted in `Thunar: Cannot open display:`.
I tried getting the authority info, `xauth list` results in `xauth: unable to generate an authority file name`.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

UPDATES:
`xhost` results in `xhost: unable to open display ""`
`echo $DISPLAY` results in nothing.
I start my vnc session by connecting via ssh and entering `vncserver`.

Comment: what is the result of `xhost` (no parameters)? And `echo $DISPLAY`? Do you directly connect via VNC (to a standalone VNC server, or are you using x11vnc?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] requested information into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!